# VPN "Could not find source connection"

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, vpn, openvpn

I am setuping VPN on Ubuntu 18.04 by:
Importing .ovpn file into Settings -> Network -> Add new VPN connection.

I am using .ovpn file downloaded from: https://www.vpnbook.com/

I am storing password for "all users".

[image: Configuration.1]

[image: Configuration.2]

However, I get "Could not find source connection" error.

Log:

> [1547293268.9296] audit: op="connection-activate"
>   uuid="f50d1a22-bb09-4f96-9052-ccab487a7066" name="de4.vpnbook.com"
>   pid=4569 uid=1000 result="fail" reason="Could not find source
>   connection."

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Jairo I tried some options, but with no luck.